# Simple mod rewrite rule not applied

Tags: mod-rewrite

This *should* be pretty straightforward. The URL is case sensitive so I want to redirect anyone who enters a lowercase 'm'.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

```
RewriteRule ^www.junaphotography.com/100moments$ http://www.junaphotography.com/100Moments/ [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RewriteRule`'s regular expression match (the first argument) matches against the **URI**, which doesn't include a hostname. You can omit the hostname:

```
RewriteRule ^/?100moments/?$ http://www.junaphotography.com/100Moments/ [L,QSA]
```

If you absolutely need to make sure the request is for the `www.junaphotography.com` host, add a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.junaphotography.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?100moments/?$ http://www.junaphotography.com/100Moments/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Unfortunately that didn't work. This did though:

`code`RedirectMatch /100moments http://www.junaphotography.com/100Moments/`code`

Comment: Did you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive somewhere before the rule?